# Can I customize the sudo "this incident will be reported" message?

Tags: sudo

Is it possible, on Linux or on BSD systems, to customize the `sudo` "this incident will be reported" message? I've gone over `man sudo` and `man sudoers` on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, a FreeBSD 10.2 machine, and a Fedora 23 machine, and I haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Sudoers Manual](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) below is the only message you are allowed to configure with the sudo conf.

```
badpass_message="Sorry, try again."
```

However to answer your question you are more than welcome to compile your own copy of sudo.

[This](http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/2c8b222a5f7f/plugins/sudoers/logging.c#l293) would be the message you are getting.

Comment: Ah, the beauty of open source. Don't like something? Change it yourself!

Comment: "Change sudo!" *but I don't know how!* "sudo change sudo!" *okay.*

Answer (score 14):

In some sense this message is already customisable because, as for many parts of GNU/Linux, `sudo` is internationalised and uses `gettext` *Native Language Support* to look up most strings to replace them by a locale version in a different language.

For example, you can see the French language file [here](http://translationproject.org/PO-files/fr/sudoers-1.8.16b1.fr.po) which has entries:

```
msgid "%s is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.\n"
msgstr "%s n'apparaît pas dans le fichier sudoers. Cet événement sera signalé.\n"

msgid "%s is not allowed to run sudo on %s.  This incident will be reported.\n"
msgstr "%s n'est pas autorisé à exécuter sudo sur %s. Cet événement sera signalé.\n"
```

So, to change the message you need to specify *for which language/locale?* and edit the appropriate NLS file. However, the user may not be using a locale, so this will have no effect.

---

Alternatively, you can use a binary editor to replace the string in `/usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so`, where it occurs, by a string of *exactly* the same size and with the same number of `%s` parameters. As this will no longer match for `gettext` translation, it will apply to all locales. Eg

```
sed < /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so 's/This incident will be reported/This incident WILL BE REPORTED/' >/tmp/sudoers.so
cmp -l /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so /tmp/sudoers.so
```

Use `cmp` to ensure you haven't corrupted the file.

Comment: Surely we can make it a different length by recompiling sudo?

Comment: @gerrit yes, the best solution would be to edit the source and recompile the program.

Comment: You could make the message shorter by padding with nul characters, since C uses nul-terminated strings.

Comment: @NateEldredge Good point.